# Передача данных между QDialog и QMainWindow

Tags: qt

У меня есть диалог, который всплывает при клике на панели меню главного окна.
В диалоге есть поле ввода и кнопка "ОК". При нажатии на эту кнопку, текст должен быть передан в главное окно и там должен быть вызван метод (или слот). Как это правильно делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну или вариант попроще:

```
//Всё это в каком-то методе в MainWindow 
MyDialog dialog(this);
if (dialog.exec()) //кнопка OK в диалоге должна вызывать или быть связана с QDialog::accept()
{
   auto dialogValue = dialog->value(); //тут забираете своё значение у диалога
   //вызываете свой метод/слот в MainWindow
}
```

Но если этот вопрос связан с предыдущим, то мой вариант наверное не подойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
QPointer<Dialog> d = new Dialog();
connect(d, &Dialog::accepted, 
[]() {
    if (d)
    {
        const QString & data = d->getValue();
        // Обработка
    }
});

d->show();
```

Comment: ..\mainwindow.cpp: In lambda function:..\mainwindow.cpp:253:39: error: 'd' is not captured
         const QString & projectName = d->getText();
                                       ^
..\mainwindow.cpp:251:37: note: the lambda has no capture-default
     connect(d, &QDialog::accepted, []() {
                                     ^
..\mainwindow.cpp:249:18: note: 'InputDialog* d' declared here
     InputDialog *d = new InputDialog(this);
                  ^

Comment: Понятно. [d] () { ... }

Comment: Прошу прощения, да d в контекст надо передать.